# How to add urlencoded parameter to httpBody in urlRequest

Tags: ios, alamofire, urlencode, swift5, urlrequest

i have created one common class for alamofire request 
i want to send parameters as `aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded`
how to add the parameters to my `urlRequest`

i have managed to add parameters as `application/json` to urlRequest using below code

```
    do {
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }
```

i need something similar for **`aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded`**

here is my parameters

```
case .ewalletData :
        return [K.APIParameterKey.token :"OP8JHOEOZ5KJW1X",K.APIParameterKey.fromMobile:"true",K.APIParameterKey.adminName:"binaryecom",K.APIParameterKey.limit:"100",K.APIParameterKey.offset:"0",K.APIParameterKey.userName:"OC6DGH"]
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the code it works for me in swift 4:
     `let postString = "your parameter="+value+"&your parameter="+value
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandle)
        task.resume()`

Comment: my parameters in this format `public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]` want to add this to httpBody

Comment: I will add another answer check that out .

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
        guard let request_url = URL(string: Url) else { return }
        let parameterDictionary = ["your parameter" : value]
        var request = URLRequest(url: request_url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "String")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else {
            return
        }
        request.httpBody = httpBody
```

Comment: you don't need to write a separate answer. you can edit the existing one and append your answer.

Comment: I want others to know about different ways of passing parameters in body .

Comment: Hi @ZahraAsqarzade i have got response successfully when Content-Type = Application/json. I want same for `aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded` with same parameters you provided in above example

Comment: just set header again : 
```request.setValue("aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "String")```

Comment: we need to add `guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else {
            return
        }` also? can you please edit the answer for me?

Comment: Still the parameters are not reaching the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195620/discussion-between-midhun-narayan-and-zahraasgharzade).